# .htaccess replace url to title without .html extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.html index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sayfa-(.*).html sayfa.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^urunler.html urunler.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^urun-kategori-(.*).html urun-kategori.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^urun-(.*).html urun.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^foto-galeri.html foto-galeri.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^galeri-(.*).html galeri.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^bloglar.html bloglar.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog-kategori-(.*).html blog-kategori.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html blog.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^iletisim.html iletisim.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^videolar.html videolar.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^video-(.*).html video.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^insan-kaynaklari.html insan-kaynaklari.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^arama.html arama.php [NC]
```

As you can see, it converts the blog.php url to title+.html

what i want is it just convert it to title.

To do this, when I change the 16th line in my code, I get a "too many redirects" error.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) blog.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

Full htaccess code: https://pastecode.io/s/2x8spyw8

Answer (score 1):

Have your .htaccess rules file in following manner. We need to combine rules for same pattern then also.

***Make sure:***

- To clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
- keep your htaccess file along side with your php files only.

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(index|urunler|foto-galeri|bloglar|iletisim|videolar|insan-kaynaklari|arama)\.html/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(sayfa|urun-kategori|urun-|galeri-|blog-kategori-|video-)/(.*)\.html/?$ $1.php?url=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/?$ blog.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: @MAMOSKO, Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.